# how to connect to users that are connected to the same local network and share information between them in an android app

Tags: java, android, networking, local, p2p

I have been searching the net for some sort of explantation on how I would get started on coding this but I haven't found anything. I know about ports and streams and basic networking stuff in java but I just can't seem to find any resources describing how this can be translating to android. I looked through the android api (https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/) but I actually don't understand any of what is written on there.

Back to the question though. The app would simply do this basic function:

- two or more people connected to the same network open the app
- when opened , the app automatically scans for all the phones connected to the same network that have this app open
- the app would then display the name of each phone with that app open connected to the same network on the screen(in activity main) as a simple array (the name of the phone would just be the bluetooth name a guess)

This might be too complex of a question to answer so If there are any resources such as videos, api, etc. , that describe this process that would be great

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you break this into smaller pieces and tackle each one individually. First you need to learn about the basics of Android programming. Start with a basic Hello, World! app. Then add some functionality for basic network communication. At each step as you get stumped, break the current task into smaller pieces. This is a fundamental skill to develop as a programmer no matter the language or platform.

Comment: https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery/

Answer (score 0):

NsdManager will fulfill all your requirement. You have to first register the service on the network through NsdManager using IP and port. Then Discover and resolve that service from another end.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/NsdChat/src/com/example/android/nsdchat/NsdHelper.java

Comment: thanks! Just one question. For the method  public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service), what exactly is a service? Like for service.getServiceName(), does that return the name of another phone thats connected to the same network? if not then how would one go about accomplishing  that?

Comment: while registering the service you have to set nsdServiceInfo.setServiceName(Build.MODEL);
nsdServiceInfo.setServiceType(_somestring._tcp.);

Comment: In OnServiceFound you have to call reolveService to get all metadata of serviceInfo.
mNsdManager.resolveService(serviceInfo, new NsdManager.ResolveListener()